# a concise recipe for installing, configuring and running minitest under autotest or Guard

Tags: ruby, guard, minitest, autotest, growl

In the past, I've run Rails + RSpec + autotest.  Now I've upgraded to ruby 2.0 and I want to use minitest in a non-Rails environment (I'm using Padrino / DataMapper).  I'm certain I'm not alone in wanting this.

What would be **really** useful is a concise recipe for installing and configuring things so the simple command:

```
$ autotest
```

or

```
$ bundle exec guard
```

will start testing everything under /test.  I have searched SO and the InterWebs, and have yet to find such a recipe.  A recipe should include:

- what gems should you include in your Gemfile?
- what commands do you run to set up the environment?
- what configuration and support files do you need to create (Rakefile?  .autotest?  etc...)
- a means for test files to `require 'test_helper'` to take care of repetitive functions

Extra credit for showing how to configure growl and spork for the full-on XP experience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmm, I don't use autotest, nowadays seems that Guard is best fit, so:

```
# Add to Gemfile
group :development do
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'    # or libnotify for linux
  gem 'rb-fsevent', require: false # or rb-inotify for linux
  gem 'guard-minitest'
  gem 'minitest'
end

# From bash
$ bundle update
$ guard init minitest # or bundle exec guard init minitest

# Edit the GuardFile, mine looks like:
guard 'minitest' do
  # with Minitest::Unit
  watch(%r|^test/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb|)
  watch(%r|^app/models/(.*)\.rb|)  { |m| "test/test_#{m[1]}.rb" }
  watch(%r|^lib/(.*)([^/]+)\.rb|)  { |m| "test/test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r|^test/helper\.rb|)      { 'test' }
end

# Here my test helper.rb. /test/helper.rb
ENV['PADRINO_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'minitest/autorun'


# Have fun!
$ bundle exec guard
```

Comment: Really great -- I've switched over to Guard and I'm liking it.  Do you happen to use growl or ruby_gntp, and do you use spork?  I'm trying to decide which notifier to use...

Comment: In my enthusiasm, I checked your answer.  But to be true to the original question, the answer needs to show what you have in your test_helper file, and perhaps test.rake or whatever makes minitest go.  Add that and I'll give you your check back!!

Comment: Okay, added it. Remember that I usually name it helper.rb and not test_helper.rb or helper_test.rb

Comment: Fair 'nuff.  I assume you're extending MiniTest::Unit::TestCase somewhere else (don't you have do define #app)?